# How is a Always on Display for Android coded?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, always-on-display

My smartphone (Samsung A21s) doesn't supoort the AOD of Samsung. So i tested several apps from the Play store. But I want an app,so i decided to code my own app, which allows me to choose my own background. I want to use the pictures from the gallery. I also want a music control for the AOD. I have a accurate idea of what I want, but I don't know how to code it. Does anybody know, how a AOD is coded? I use Kotlin and I'm working with Android Studio.

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you just need to keep the screen on while you're using your app, you can use a wakelock: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#screen

Comment: its not that kind of a AOD. Just download AOD on the playstore, and then you'll know what I mean

Comment: That is basically how they work though, it's an app that prevents the screen from turning off when idle, so it's constantly displayed even if you're not interacting with it. Even if you want it to turn off sometimes but turn on every so often, or when you touch the device, you'll still need a wakelock to turn the screen on again. If you want to make an app that behaves like that I'd start there. Trying to replicate an actual Always On Display (a feature baked into the OS/first-party software on supported devices) without the same access and guaranteed hardware support will be hacky though