# Are there options to develop an AOD app for samsung/android?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, always-on-display

I want to create a simple app that would have a list of To-Dos that show up on the Always On Display (AOD) on Samsung/Android. I thought it could be useful for people like me who constantly need reminding of what they have to do.

From what I understand Android natively does not provide an API to interact directly with the AOD but Samsung has an SDK that could provide the required functionality. This is a new kind of project for me so if anyone could share some wisdom/ideas on how I could get  it done hesitate to share. I am also not set on a tech stack and I am curios what people think is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you provide a link to any publicly available SDK? Similar question: [How is a Always on Display for Android coded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73098109/295004)